# Can't fire another class with onclicklistener

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

Hi I have created an app with four tabs in a recyclerview each tab has a listview within it which I am trying to make clickable.

I have added an onitemclicklistener in the adapter and each fragment but when I run the code the click is not firing.  I have added android:clickable="true" in the card view xml but it is still not firing.

My Adapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private String[] mDataset;

private onItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

interface onItemClickListener{
    void onItemClicked(int position);
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener
                                           onItemClickListener){
    this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public CardView mCardView;
    public TextView mTextView;

    public MyViewHolder(View v){
        super(v);

        mCardView = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_text);

    }

}

public MyAdapter(String[] myDataset){
    mDataset = myDataset;
}

@Override
public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_item, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position){
    holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset[position]);
    holder.mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (onItemClickListener != null) {
                onItemClickListener.onItemClicked(position);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() { return mDataset.length; }
```

}

My Fragment

```
public class LOneFragment extends Fragment {

public LOneFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);

    RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_recycler_view);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(new String[]{"Example One", "Example Two", "Example Three", "Example Four", "Example Five" , "Example Six" , "Example Seven"});
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new MyAdapter.onItemClickListener()

    { @Override public void onItemClicked(int position) {

        if (position == 1);{

        Intent intent = new Intent(LOneFragment.this.getActivity(), Bradford.class);
        startActivity(intent);}
    } });
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);

    return rootView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to load adapter at first and only then add it to RecyckerView:

```
    adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new MyAdapter.onItemClickListener()

    { @Override public void onItemClicked(int position) {

        if (position == 1);{

        Intent intent = new Intent(LOneFragment.this.getActivity(), Bradford.class);
        startActivity(intent);}
    } });

rv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Also, intent will be called only if you click on second position in view (because of if statement), check if click is called by logging it or with debug.